# Why do I get a "lwcX is not a constructor" error at runtime?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have two "headless" LWC modules (LWCs that have no template or CSS and that simply export some items to be used elsewhere). Let's call them "lwcX" and "lwcY".

In this case lwcX is the default exported class in the "lwcX" LWC. The lwcY module includes a function, let's call it "createAbc" that is exported. The "lwcX" code uses this function. Additionally, the "createAbc" function internally uses the exported "lwcX" class. It is when "lwcY" is being initialized that the "lwcX is not a constructor" error is thrown.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

LWC JavaScript code is not used "as-is" but rather gets pre-processed to generate the actual runnable JavaScript used at runtime.

The problem seen here is due to the way the generated code handles cross-references between modules. Essentially the "LWC module" becomes a function that receives a bunch of various parameters that are themselves the dependencies for that "module".

In this case the two modules have mutual (or cyclic) dependency. The LWC pre-processing approach simply cannot handle this scenario and the code fails with this exception during the invocation of this "module function"; the cyclic dependency has not been resolved at the appropriate time (since modules are initialized in bottom-up dependency sequence by the look of it) and the dependency comes in as undefined.

You resolve this issue by breaking the cyclic dependency, at least at the module level (it is fine to have cyclic dependencies within a module), via refactoring of the code.